# How to run solana devnet validator in MacOS/Linux?

Tags: validator

I am able to run the command solana-test-validator but when I try to run solana-validator I get the error

```
[2022-11-23T07:42:22.902908000Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8899, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
[2022-11-23T07:42:27.909310000Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8900, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
[2022-11-23T07:42:32.911957000Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8000, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
```

I have opened up those ports from the firewall and still get the same error. So how to run it?

Also if its closed by my ISP, and I have no option to call them to open the ports, will there be any other alternatives?
And is there any docker image for macOS?

Answer (score 1):

I would reconsider trying to run a networked validator on Apple hardware. `solana-test-validator` is great for building apps and local testing, but you cannot run a networked validator on a standard laptop. You should check that your machine satisfies the validator hardware requirements: https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs#hardware-recommendations.

I believe the Apple M1 chips only have 8 cores whereas Solana validators need a minimum of 12 and perform best with 16 or more. Everyone running validators on devnet/testnet/mainnet today generally use a bare metal Ubuntu instances.

If you're interested in running a validator, definitely checkout the Solana Validator Guidebook (https://www.solana-validator-guidebook.com/). You can also contact Solana Foundation's server program to get in touch with an edge provider who can supply you with a bare metal instance for running a node.